# Como configurar o User Id do GTAG em arquivo JS externo pegando variável PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, google, google-analytics-api

Como uso PHP no backend, para configurar o user id inline basta dar um `echo` da variável `$userId`, [por ex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40189304/how-to-implement-google-analytics-tracking-code-with-clientid-into-php-footer):

```
   if (isset($userId)) {
        $gacode = "ga('create', 'xxx', 'auto', {'userId': $userId});";
        echo sprintf($gacode, $userId);
        }     
   else {
        $gacode = "ga('create', 'xxx', 'auto');";
        echo sprintf($gacode);
        }
```

Porém como quero usar o código de acompanhamento num arquivo `.js` externo (chamado no final do HTML da página `.php`), ao invés de utilizar `inline`, isso não funciona.

O código de acompanhamento é basicamente este:

```
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
gtag('js', new Date());
gtag('config', 'XXXXXXX', { 'user_id': 'USER_ID' });
```

Este código está no arquivo que criei `gtag_user.js`, que coloquei abaixo da lib do tagmanager (no final da página onde a variável `$userId` está declarada).

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-XXXXX"></script>
<script src="https://www.site.com/view/js/gtag_user.js"></script>
```

Onde `USER_ID` precisa ser igual a variável `$userId` do PHP. Fiz algumas tentativas com `ajax` mas não deu certo também. Isso é possível? Como?

Comment: Para eu me situar? Onde está marcado com `<script>` é PHP? O código que não está marcado é JS? Se for não seria o caso de trocar essa marcação de lugar?

Comment: @Augusto Vasques Sim, marquei..  já retirei. Valeu por informar. Esse php fica no meio do JS, pra escrever o js conforme o usuário esteja ou não logado.

Answer (score 2):

Como o arquivo que contém o HTML é `.php` você pode fazer isso:

```
<script>const USER_ID = '<?php echo $userId; ?>';</script> <!-- aqui é declarada a constante -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-XXXXX"></script>
<script src="https://www.site.com/view/js/gtag_user.js"></script>
```

No script você precisa alterar e colocar a constante no objeto:

```
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
gtag('js', new Date());
gtag('config', 'XXXXXXX', { 'user_id': USER_ID }); // retirei as aspas
```

Desta forma você conseguirá usar em qualquer lugar que você precisar. Exemplo:

```
<script>

    if(USER_ID == ''){
        // usuario não está logado
    } else {
        // verifica o usuário
    }

</script>
```

Uma outra forma é gerar o script com o php:

```
// user id
$userId = 12345;
// arquivo JS
$arquivo = file_get_contents("https://www.site.com/view/js/gtag_user.js");
// substitui tudo o que tier USER_ID pelo valor $userId
$script = str_replace("USER_ID", $userId, $arquivo);
// mostra o resultado
echo "<script>$script</script>";
```

**Usando cookies**

Nos comentários o OP revelou uma outra forma de trabalhar utilizando cookies. Para ilustrar, eu criei o seguinte exemplo:

O php gera o cookie:

```
    if (isset($userId)) {
        setcookie("USER_ID", $userId, time()+3600, "/");
    }
```

E o valor é recuperado pelo javascript:

```
    const getUserId = () => {
        let val = null;
        decodeURIComponent(document.cookie).split(";").forEach(item => {
            let i = item.split("=");
            if(i[0] === 'USER_ID'){
                val = i[1].trim();
            }
        });
        return val;
    } 

    const USER_ID = getUserId(); // recupera o valor
```

Com isso, a constante `USER_ID` poderá ser usada nos demais scripts.

Comment: Andrei, mas no caso não quero usar nada inline (a `const` dentro da tag <script>). De qualquer forma é uma boa solução se puder usar inline. +1

Comment: @gustavox entendi.... Tem uma outra maneira. Vou coloca-la para você.

Comment: @gustavox antes de eu criar, deixa eu te explica mais ou menos como funcionaria... Eu pegaria todo o coneúdo `js` e substituiria tudo que tiver `USER_ID ` pela valor que você quer usar. O que você acha?

Comment: Não sei se entendi... o js é estático né, não pode ser reescrevendo o próprio js pq quebraria para os outros usuários...

Comment: @gustavox ele não será reescrito no arquivo. O arquivo servirá de modelo/base. Entendeu?

Comment: Acho que entendi, deve dar certo então.

Comment: @gustavox Eu vou dar uma saída, e depois eu posto

Comment: Tranquilo, obrigado pela força. abs

Comment: @gustavox ai está um outro modo de gerar o script

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96710/discussion-between-gustavox-and-andrei-coelho).

Comment: Então, infelizmente não deu certo. como disse no chat, não posso ter nada inline. Acho que só usando cookie ou ajax mesmo. Estou tentando aqui, mas reabri a pergunta e ofereci uma recompensa.

Comment: @gustavox tranquilo man! =)

Comment: Andrei, consegui resolver usando cookies através deste artigo: https://www.analyticsmania.com/post/google-analytics-user-id-with-google-tag-manager/#gref Tem várias outras formas, mas é preciso configurar no tagmanager.com, mudar o código de acompanhamento... Então queria sugerir que vc incluísse na sua reposta esta referência, só pra ficar mais completa pra eu poder marcar como resolvida...

Comment: @gustavox eu vou ler amanhã com calma a respeito o link que você enviou. Mas obrigado pelo feedback.